# ReferenceContainer is appearing on wrong position, XML

Tags: magento2, xml

I'm using Magestores Bannerslider with custom templates in order to create Sliders.

I want to place the slider above page.main and below the nav.section element.

This is my code in `cms_index_index.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>

        <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper" before="page.main">
            <block class="Magestore\Bannerslider\Block\SliderItem" name="slider">
                <action method="setSliderId">
                    <argument name="sliderId" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                </action>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>

    </body>

</page>
```

However, the element appears after `page.main`. From my understanding, placing it before that element should be enough, but it does not work. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following way:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
            <block class="Magestore\Bannerslider\Block\SliderItem" name="slider" before="page.main">
                <action method="setSliderId">
                    <argument name="sliderId" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                </action>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Didn't you mean "use block instead of referenceContainer"? Where exactly have I used a htmlClass? Just curious, want to understand exactly what I have done wrong.

Comment: Check https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Theme/view/base/page_layout/empty.xml#L13

Comment: "page-main" is not container name, It's html class name.

Comment: Thats what I expected, but I didn't used `page-main`, but `page.main`. But then it's clear what you've meant.

Comment: Uhh! yes right. Check updated answer.